# Expected value of random walk over signed network

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value, random-walk, random-graphs, network

A connected weighted graph $G(V,E,W)$ is give, where $w_{uv}$ corresponds to the probability to jump from node $u$ to node $v$. Also, a function $l$ maps nodes with positive and negative labels, where $V_+$ are the nodes having positive label (+1) and $V_-$ are the ones having negative label (-1). Assuming to have a random walk starting visiting nodes in the graph (with no assumption about the starting node) is possible to estimate (in expected value) $S$, i.e. the number of steps presenting **consecutively** same label (positive or negative)?

I'm trying to understand which is the average length of subsequences of having the same label without any assumption on edges distribution (in a random graph configuration).

Comment: Without any assumptions whatsoever, the expected value is $2$, since if we don't know anything about $V_+$ and $V_-$ and how they interact with the graph and its weights, then each step has a fifty-fifty chance of switching to the other label. I don't think that's the sort of answer you're looking for, though; can you clarify?

Comment: Knowing the relative size of the two groups should not help? Anyway knowing adjacency matrix do you think should be possible to get an expected length of subsequence? I'm imagining a matrix where, depending on the seed node (row-i) we then know the expected value

Answer (score 1):

If you have the adjacency matrix and want to compute the expected time to stay in $V^-$ (for instance) starting from various vertices in $V^-$, then we first want to simplify the adjacency matrix to get rid of the useless information about $V^+$. We want to work with the $|V^-|$ by $|V^-|$ matrix $A$ where the $(u,v)$ entry is still $w_{uv}$, but only the vertices from $V^-$ are present. (So instead of summing to $1$, row $u$ should sum to the probability that a transition from $u$ leads to another vertex in $V^-$.)

Then if we start with a column vector $\mathbf x$ describing a probability distribution over states in $V^-$ (which could just have probability $1$ on a single state), then $A \mathbf x$ will be a sort-of-probability distribution over the state after one step: it will tell us the probabilities for every next state in $V^-$, but transitions to $V^+$ will just disappear. The sum of the components of $A\mathbf x$, which is $\mathbf 1^{\mathsf T}A\mathbf x$ algebraically, will be the probability of staying in $V^-$ after one step.

More generally, $\mathbf 1^{\mathsf T}A^k \mathbf x$ will give us the probability of staying in $V^-$ after $k$ steps. So if we want to know the total number of vertices we visited in $V^-$ before moving to $V^+$, that's going to be $\mathbf 1^{\mathsf T}(I + A + A^2 + \dots )\mathbf x$, which simplifies to $\mathbf 1^{\mathsf T}(I - A)^{-1}\mathbf x$.

So $\mathbf 1^{\mathsf T}(I - A)^{-1}$ tells you the vector of expected lengths of stays in $V^-$ for all starting vertices in $V^-$. (It counts the starting vertex as well, so if a vertex always transitions to $V^+$, it'll have an expected length of $1$.)

We can do this for both $V^+$ and $V^-$ at the same time if we work with the bigger matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}A^- & 0 \\ 0 & A^+\end{bmatrix},$$ where $A^-$ is the $V^- \to V^-$ transition matrix and $A^+$ is the $V^+ \to V^+$ transition matrix. (So we take the adjacency matrix for the graph and wipe out the entries that go from one set to the other.) But this is a block matrix and the inverses $(I - A^-)^{-1}$ and $(I - A^+)^{-1}$ are going to be completely independent, anyway.

Comment: Great, thank you for the detailed answer. I'm wondering now if there exists some reference about absorbing random walks of different colors (like this where we have a partition of two colors). I would be interested to understand if some relationships exist between the two distinct absorbing random walks, even if independent.